# Same "Google Translation API key" on multiple websites?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-translate

on one of my websites, I use the "Google Translation API key". Can I use the same key on other websites, or do I need to create a separate key?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same api key within the same project.

However you will be bound by the same quota.   They will share it.  If you create two separate projects for each site and a key in each project they get their own quota.

Comment: Hi DalmTo,

Thank you for your answer.

My apologies; I am a bit ignorant in this field.

So, if I understand correctly:

I can Use API X for website translations for website A
And I can use API X for translations website B
But then they use the same quotas. Is that correct?

Kind regards, Marty